# Recover MBR after overwriting it with an empty one

Tags: windows, boot, ntfs, mbr, gparted

I've accidentally messed up my Windows XP hard drive.

I wanted to copy the MBR from this disk to a new SSD, but I've done the opposite. I do not have a shadow copy of that volume and thought that just messing with the MBR can be recovered. Unfortunately, I'm not able to bring my Windows XP HDD back to life.

I used this command `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` and I know that I've overwritten just the first 512 clusters. The problem is I can't revert it.

Recovery steps attempted:

- I've tried FIXMBR and FIXBOOT using the Windows XP installation disk.
- I've also tried also using TestDisk from a GParted Live CD - it successfully found my partition table, wrote it, but still no success.
- I tried rebuilding bootcfg and MFT - the operation succeeded, but still no luck.
- Under the Windows XP recovery console, I tried both `CHKDSK /P /R` and even repairing the whole installation - but I still can't boot into my Windows. It just throws up `Read Error Occured, Press Ctrl+Alt+Del`.

If I hook up this drive up via a USB case for SATA drives, it throws up a Windows error 0x000007b while booting (I can see the Windows XP boot screen for a few seconds).

Can you please advise me what else I can do? (Or what I've done wrong in any of my attempts?)

TestDisk can list my files and I'm able to copy them to an external drive, but I want to avoid a clean installation.

Comment: You have not overwritten the first 512 clusters (luckily, that would've been between 512 and 4096 sectors), you have overwritten a single sector.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the MBR using [Easy Recovery Essentials](https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/). The process is as follows for Windows XP:

1. Download [Easy Recovery Essentials](https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/) and burn it to a bootable CD
2. Boot Easy Recovery Essentials and select the Automated Repair Option
3. Select your drive and select Automated Repair
4. The program will run and will attempt to recreate your MBR (this can take some time)
5. Reboot and that's it.

This should work for any OS from Windows XP through to Windows 8.1.

I hope that this works for you.